# Sizing Issue: Libre Office Options Menu is way too small!

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, fonts, resize

I can’t figure out how to increase the font size in libre office and 4k downloader and keepass in lubuntu 20.10. My main menu in libreoffice is nice and big but when I open tools>options I can’t see a damn thing without squinting (same story with keepass), it’s very frustrating. I really want to learn this software well but it’s just too frustrating to look into at the moment. C'mon libre office, what am I an Eagle?

I’m on a 15” acer aspire e-15.

Any tips? Am I the only one?? :)

Comment: Do you have a HiDPI screen? What is your screen resolution? Can you post a screenshot? KDE does not support fractional scaling of GTK apps (e.g. libreoffice) at the moment (which means, they would have small fonts), and I suspect the same issue persists in LXQT. In that case, you can switch to a GTK based desktop environment.

Comment: Most users of Lubuntu/LXQt won't be using HiDPi screens, after all HiDPi requires more code to handle which goes against the aim of being *light*

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can set your screen resolution lower and your in-screen scaler will then scale everything normal. This could differ from laptop to laptop, but it works for me (on all screens I've tested). In Linux you can do the same at your screen settings, and because this kind of scaling is done via hardware instead of software, it will also work on Linux.